# FAQ page. 'Read less' option content, JQuery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a page with FAQ in wordpress. I want to add `read more` and `read less` options. `Read more` is working fine, but I have some issues with `read less`.

When i click, read more the content expand. Than when i click on read less the content stays the same. I need the content to go back to the shorter version on read less.

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="moreExpandWrapp">
    <div class="moreExpandContent" id="aboutExpand">
         <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
    $(".moreExpandContent").each(function () {
        var s = $(this).html(),
            self = $(this);
        if (s.split(' ').length > 100) {
            self.html(s.split(' ').slice(0, 100).join(' ') + " ... " + '<div class="read-more-bg"><a href="#" class="read-more">Read more</a></div>');

            self.find('a.read-more').click(function () {
                self.html((s) + "" + '<div class="read-more-bg"><a href="#" class="read-less">Read less</a></div>');
            })

            self.find('a.read-less').click(function () {
                self.html(s.split(' ').slice(0, 100).join(' ') + " ... " + '<div class="read-more-bg"><a href="#" class="read-more">Read more</a></div>');
            })
        }
    });
```

Comment: What issues do you have exactly with read less?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: When i click read more the content expand. When i click read less nothing happens. I would like the content to shrink when i click read less.

Comment: Is there two separate blocks for Less content and More content ?

Comment: No. I use the same block.